# Linux Pandas.date_range doesn't include 02 for begin of dst even to utc timezone

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
pd.date_range(start='2024-01-01', end='2024-12-31', freq='5T', tz='UTC', name='start_dt')
```

**doesn't include 2024-03-10 02:00:00 thru 2024-03-10 02:55:00**

If I used UTC as timezone, it should include 2024-03-10 02:00:00 thru 2024-03-10 02:55:00

Comment: I can't reproduce this on my system (pandas 2.0.1), I see all the times `'2024-03-10 02:00:00+00:00', '2024-03-10 02:05:00+00:00',
               '2024-03-10 02:10:00+00:00', '2024-03-10 02:15:00+00:00',
               '2024-03-10 02:20:00+00:00', '2024-03-10 02:25:00+00:00',
               '2024-03-10 02:30:00+00:00', '2024-03-10 02:35:00+00:00',
               '2024-03-10 02:40:00+00:00', '2024-03-10 02:45:00+00:00',
               '2024-03-10 02:50:00+00:00', '2024-03-10 02:55:00+00:00',` as expected

Comment: If you try it on windows, you won't see the issue.  This issue only happens on Linux or try it on AWS Lambda.

Comment: I can't reproduce on Ubuntu 22.04 either using pandas 1.x or 2.x